# Generate random object

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have someone who is responsible for opening / closing the window, I am trying to have one of the three gifts displayed randomly when opened. While there is no progress, how can I do this.

I understand that I need to do this through state.random, but now I don’t understand how. Apparently I'm completely blond ))))

// start open box

```
var TOGGLE_BOX = '[GiftBox] Toggle';
var toggleBox = function () {
  return { type: TOGGLE_BOX };
};
//REDUCERS (Update)
var DEFAULT = { open: false, wasOpen: false };
var reducer = function (state, action) {
  if (state === void 0) {state = DEFAULT;}
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_BOX:{
        return {
          open: state.open ? false : true,
          wasOpen: state.open };

      }
    default:return state;}
};
var store = Redux.createStore(reducer, DEFAULT);
var mapStateToProps = function (state) {
  return { open: state.open, wasOpen: state.wasOpen };
};
var mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
  return { dispatch: dispatch };
};

var cGiftBox = function (_a) {
  var wasOpen = _a.wasOpen,open = _a.open,dispatch = _a.dispatch;

  return React.createElement("div", { className: "floor" },

  React.createElement("div", { className: "box" },
  open ?
  React.createElement("button", { className: "heart-gift", }, "gift1") :
  React.createElement(React.Fragment, null),

  React.createElement("div", { className: open ?
    'lid open' :
    wasOpen ?
    'lid close' :
    'lid', onClick: function (e) {return dispatch(toggleBox());} },

  React.createElement("div", { className: "qcube" }, open ? '!' : '?'),
  React.createElement("div", { className: "face ltop" }),
  React.createElement("div", { className: "face lleft" }),
  React.createElement("div", { className: "face lright" })),

  React.createElement("div", { className: "face top" }),
  React.createElement("div", { className: "face left" }),
  React.createElement("div", { className: "face right" }),
));
};
// connect and render
var Provider = ReactRedux.Provider,connect = ReactRedux.connect;
var GiftBox = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(cGiftBox);
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Provider, { store: store },
React.createElement(GiftBox, null)), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Why you're using React in this weird way, mate ?

Comment: what's wrong? and what exactly is my mistake?

Comment: Please don't tag irrelevant tags on to your post. This is not a cascading stylesheet question.